# How to redirect to url after j_security_check login

Tags: jakarta-ee, j-security-check

I use j_security_check to authenticate my Java EE web app.

I have 2 groups; user and admin. Both of these groups have a own folder in the weg pages; user has "/secure", admin has "/admin". After a person is authenticated with j_security_check I would like based on their group to redirected to their associated web folder. Now they just stay at the login page. The authenticating part of my app works fine, if I log in as an user I can access /secure but not /admin, and vice versa.

Is this possible and how? I coulden't find any information or a solution online.

Edit: Maybe some handy information for a solution, I also use JSF in my app. But I don't use any JSF to login. Login form is pure html with the j_security_check stuff.

Edit 2: The root file for my main web folder is the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering how I solved it, I forgot to specify the roles in the web.xml, like this:

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>skipper</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Thanks @Franck for taking his time to solve this problem trough chat!

Answer (score 2):

You can have a mere web Servlet which will handle a common secure /login path ([@WebServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html)) between your different roles and redirect to the page based on the current authenticated user's role. You can use the [HttpRequest.isUserInRole()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isUserInRole-java.lang.String-) method and then redirect your user to the page you want ([HttpResponse.sendRedirect()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect-java.lang.String-))

Comment: I did this on my WebFilter I already have: http://pastebin.com/JBd28jd9

It just goes in the else statement everytime, the role name are correct, I double checked in my "glassfish-web.xml"

I checked that I was authenticated and could acces the pages I am allowed to see with the current role from the authenticated user.

Comment: Is the WebFilter triggered on a secured url?

Comment: Only on "/", "/login.xhtml","/login_error.xhtml". As I only need the user be redirected to their respective "/secure" or "/admin" if they go to the login page, even though they are logged in.

Comment: Wait I know what you mean, those pages don't have a constraint configured.

Comment: Should I just add a security constaint to those pages and allow everyone?

Comment: You should secure the WebFilter url and allow everyone in order to force the authentication. Then you'll have a meaningful PRincipal.

Comment: I added the pages to a constraint: http://pastebin.com/D9fjSm9a

But the code in the filter is still going only in the else statement?

Comment: If I do this "System.out.println(req.getUserPrincipal());" in the else statement it shows the correct value when I am auhenticated.

Comment: you said the roles are bound into glassfish-web.xml but you should refer to the ones defined in your web.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94213/discussion-between-wesley-egbertsen-and-franck).

Answer (score 1):

How About:
Create a `redirect.jsp` file with the next content:

```
<%response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/redirect");%>
```

Then make the `redirect.jsp` to be the welcome-file in the `web.xml`:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And the last step is to create the servlet which checks the role and redirects appropriately